# Ruby on Rails - LDAP based authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ldap, netldap

this is my first post on SO, but I have been reader for long time :)
I'm currently working on LDAP authentication for Rails app. I'm using ruby Net::LDAP library - I'm abble to succesfully bind and login using technical account and search for a specific user. What I don't know how to do, is how to verify finded AD user password with the one he provided during logon. Because of AD policy restriction, I can make binding only from the technical account - so the use sollution with binding every logging user to AD cannot be used here.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `.bind_as`: According to the docs
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-net-ldap/Net/LDAP#bind_as-instance_method
it is for testing authentication credentials.